# Cannot use [noexcept] in MIDL 3

Tags: c++-winrt, midl

In this year's Build Talk [C++/WinRT 2.0: Faster and smarter in the open](https://youtu.be/X41j_gzSwOY), Kenny Kerr demonstrates the [use of the `[noexcept]` attribute in IDL](https://youtu.be/X41j_gzSwOY?t=1003), providing better optimization opportunities to the compiler by eliding exception handling at the ABI.

Trying this for myself, however, I ended up with MIDL compiler errors. The following stripped down IDL file

```
namespace NS
{
    interface IMyInterface
    {
        [noexcept] String DoStuff();
    };
}
```

produces the following diagnostic output:

> ```
> error MIDL2025: [msg]syntax error [context]: expecting . near "]"
> error MIDL2009: [msg]undefined symbol [context]: noexcept.String
> error MIDL2025: [msg]syntax error [context]: expecting ] or , near "DoStuff"
> error MIDL2025: [msg]syntax error [context]: expecting . near "("
> error MIDL2026: [msg]cannot recover from earlier syntax errors; aborting compilation
> ```

Am I doing something wrong here, or is the `[noexcept]` attribute not yet available in the GA releases of Visual Studio (16.1.4) or the Windows SDK (10.0.18362.0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a newer version of MIDLRT. This feature is currently available in the insider builds of the Windows SDK and will ship with the next major update of Windows.